# Maya SDK Rotation Anim Curves to Local Quaternion

Tags: sdk, maya

I am trying to convert a X,Y,Z rotation from the rotate anim curves to a local quaternion of a bone.

I've read that "Total Rotation = Pre Rotation * Rotation * Post Rotation

where Pre Rotation = Joint Orient,  and Post Rotation is Rotate Orient

How exactly out of Maya SDK do I get these  Pre and Post rotations?  -- What exactly are they?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-SDK/cpp-ref/class-m-fn-ik-joint-html.html

getOrientation and getScaleOrientation functions